# Yii2 failed passing Image from PHP into Exported Excel, it passing the PHP Script into Excel

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to insert image from Yii2 into exported Excel;

This is the code :

```
<?php
 $logo = Html::img("@web/img/Logo.jpg", ['width' => '60px', 'height' => '50px', 'margin-top' => '-10px']);
    $downloadedTime = $downloadTZ->format('Y-m-d');
    $bulan = \Yii::t('app', $month);
    $filename = 'Report'.'xls';
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("refresh:0;url=../master/index");
    echo $logo;
    echo "Name\t";
    echo "Class\t";
    echo "Age\t";
    echo "\r\n";
```

?>

if I `echo $logo;` the printed in browser, but in Excel it will print the code not the image, just like this 
[image: Exported Excel]

Why does this happen? and How do I can solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do that with PHPExcel class and then calling PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing;

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('img/logo.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

like this.